# how to remove specific url from text in regex

Tags: php, regex

I am in problem to remove specific `url` from text but keep the text or html tags between the anchor tag. But I cannot remove it. I remove the specific url from the text but, cannot get the text or html between the anchor tag. Here is my code to remove specific url from the text.

```
preg_replace(|<a [^>]*href="http://www.microsoft.com[^"]*"[^>]*>.*</a>|iU, '', $a)
```

and Here is the sample

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/">   <img src="http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-in/CMSImages/MMD_TCFamily_1006_540x304.jpg?version=ac2c5995-fde2-b40b-3f2a-b6a0baa88250" class="mscom-image feature-image" alt="Learn about Lumia 950 and Lumia 950 XL." width="540" height="304">   </a>
```

I want to get the img tag or any text between that anchor tag having the specific url.

Did I make any mistake in my code. Please correct me. I want this in regex in php Please help me.

Comment: Is that your actual PHP? What happens on the current execution? Is the source code all on one line?

Comment: first of all, escape the foward slashs.

Comment: @lbarros forward slashes aren't special, don't need to be escaped. The `|` is the delimiter.

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the info @chris85.

Comment: Well I guess the OP has vanished. 1. Look at the quotes. 2. Look at modifiers, http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php (specifically `s`) 3. Consider a parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we go again...
[Don't use regexes to parse html](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/797495), use an html parser, [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for example:

```
$html = <<< EOF
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/">   <img src="http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-in/CMSImages/MMD_TCFamily_1006_540x304.jpg?version=ac2c5995-fde2-b40b-3f2a-b6a0baa88250" class="mscom-image feature-image" alt="Learn about Lumia 950 and Lumia 950 XL." width="540" height="304">  SOME TEXT </a>
EOF;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach($xpath->query("//a[contains(@href,'microsoft.com')]") as $element ){
        $img = $xpath->query('./img',$element)->item(0);
        echo $img->getAttribute('src'); // img source
        echo $img->getAttribute('alt'); // img alt text
        echo $element->textContent; //text inside the a tag
}
//http://c.s-microsoft.com/en-in/CMSImages/MMD_TCFamily_1006_540x304.jpg?version=ac2c5995-fde2-b40b-3f2a-b6a0baa88250
//Learn about Lumia 950 and Lumia 950 XL.
//SOME TEXT
```

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/nD49rJ)